# Delete Session Files and Prevent Returning

Tags: magento2, database, session, user

I've already attempted to delete session files, but they come back one at a time and slowly... Huh? Can someone explain why please and help me permanently delete them please?

I can not locate them in the database as well.

I'd also like to know how to automatically remove old session files when this weird 'bug' is resolved.

Magento 2.2.4

*SOLVED* Turns out the garbage collector was disabled.

Comment: Well, the sessions need to be stored _somewhere_ - either in the database, in redis, or in the file system. If you don't configure redis or the database, the session data needs to be stored in the file system... which is then PHP core functionality: https://serverfault.com/questions/138214/are-php-session-files-ever-deleted ** Update: You just added the information that you use M2. In that case, I do not understand the information about the local.xml file. M2 should not have a local.xml file. Could you explain, please?

Comment: They are stored in /var/session/ but when deleted they return somehow.
** Update: Sorry, I don't know what file controls or shows where the session files are stored (db/file) in M2 then. Could you tell me?

Comment: Everytime someone browses on the website, a session file will be created. That's a feature. :) It helps identifying the user across multiple requests. Take care: If you delete them in a production system, users' shopping carts will suddenly be empty...

Comment: I understand their purpose, just not how they are implemented, what controls where I choose to store them, and how to successfully remove old/expired sessions permanently without them returning.

Comment: My root's php.ini file only contains `session.save_path=/home/***/public_html/var/session` "***" for privacy. It doesn't contain other config options though.

Comment: Oh, okay! It looks like this is all standard php session stuff in your case (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/sessions.html "default file-based session storage"). People here https://serverfault.com/questions/138214/are-php-session-files-ever-deleted figured out how/when they are deleted - but that's all controlled via PHP settings. You might need to modify your php settings - if that's possible with your hoster.